# Robotium - Set screenshot save path doesn't work

Tags: android, robotium

I want to save the screenshot to `/sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/testLogin/en/`.

The following code work perfectly fine. It creates a `testLogin` folder in `Robotium-Screenshots` and save the screenshot:

```
String path = "/sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/testLogin/";
solo.getConfig().screenshotSavePath = "/sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/";
solo.takeScreenshot("abc");
```

But when I change the path to:

```
String path = "/sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/testLogin/en/";
```

I cannot find `testLogin` and `en` folders and screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, it doesn't work because the directory does not exist yet. With the following code, I check if the directory exists and create the directory if it does not.

```
File directory = new File(path);
if (!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdirs();
}
```

After making sure the directory exists, you can take the screenshot. I hope this helped!!